# why do I get an error when trying to run swift language in mac terminal with $ swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to run swift in mac terminal with this simple command:

```
$ swift
```

but I get a load of errors every time

```
ImportError: No module named six
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'run_one_line' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

continued for about a thousand lines ...

do I need to install a package or something

Comment: I assume you have Xcode installed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Brew to install Python versions on your macOS ?

I fix it uninstall python version installed from Brew.

```
brew uninstall --force python
```

That suited me !